# Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for en php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

que tal estoy tratando de crear un script con copia para una carpeta compartida la cuestion es que ya trate de ponerle los permisos a ambas carpetas y ya tienen todos los accesos permitidos solo nose por que no me deja tomar mis archivos de una ruta a otra
aqui esta mi carpeta que si tiene permisos pero es de otra maquina ya que son dos maquinas la cuales una toma el archivo y otra lo copia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
/*date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fecha=strftime("%d %h");

$from = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\post\aqui.txt*.*';
$to = '\\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\Nueva carpeta\ '.$fecha;

exec("copy $from \"$to\" /Y");

if (!file_exists($to)) {
    mkdir($to, 0777, true);

   

}*/

$from = '\\10.100.14.12\Sterling\Recibe\GEST_CMG.txt*.*';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fecha=strftime("%d %h");
$to = '\\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\ '.$fecha;

// Validar primero si existe y es directorio
if (!file_exists($to) || !is_dir($to)) {
    // Verifica que realmente se creó la carpeta
    if(!mkdir($to, 0777, true)) {
       die("No se puede crear la carpeta $to");
    }
}
exec("copy $from \"$to\" /Y");

/*el segundo */

$fromER = '\\10.100.14.12\Sterling\Recibe\R200_CMG.txt*.*';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

$fecha=strftime("%d %h");
$te = '\\192.168.23.1\bancomer2\Respaldo_A200\ '.$fecha;

// Validar primero si existe y es directorio
if (!file_exists($te) || !is_dir($te)) {
    // Verifica que realmente se creó la carpeta
    if(!mkdir($te, 0777, true)) {
       die("No se puede crear la carpeta $te");
    }
}
exec("copy $fromER \"$te\" /Y");

echo (substr(printf('%o', fileperms($fromER)), -4));


var_dump($fromER);

var_dump($te);
```

entonces ya lo valide localmente y si me funciona bien
pero ya con las dos carpetas diferentes compartidas me da el siguiente error

Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for C:\xampp\htdocs\post\R200_CMG.txt*.* in C:\xampp\htdocs\catchClab.php on line 47
01string(36) "C:\xampp\htdocs\post\R200_CMG.txt*.*" string(42) "\10.100.99.74\C\xampp\htdocs\post1\ 21 Oct"

Comment: Estás asignando permiso solo para administradores, entonces debes asegurarte que PHP se ejecute bajo alguno de esos usuarios o dar permisos al usuario correspondiente. Si no sabes cual es, usa [`get_current_user()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-current-user.php)

Comment: me aparece Propietario script actual: SYSTEM

Comment: que puedo hacer hay

Comment: Si tienes XAMPP configurado como servicio, puedes configurar el usuario con el que se ejecuta, solo localiza el servicio, haz doble clic y haz los cambios necesarios en la pestaña "Iniciar sesión"